# Multidimensional list(array) reassignment problem

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy, netcdf

Good day coders and codereses,

I am writing a piece of code that goes through a pile of statistical data and returns what I ask from it. To complete its task the method reads from one multidimensional array and writes into another one. The piece of code giving me problems is:

```
writer.variables[variable][:, :, :, :] = reader.variables[variable][offset:, 0, 0:5, 3]
```

The size of both slices is `27:1:6:1` but it throws up an exception:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I am flabbergasted.

Thank you.

Comment: Sheesh. I'll try not to ask any more question until the sleeping pattern is sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a slice with `0:5` is not 6 as you say: it's 5. The upper limit is excluded in slicing (as it most always is, in Python). Don't know whether that's your actual problem or just a typo in your question...